# PHP does not work after certification lets encrypt

Tags: php, nginx, web, lets-encrypt

After I finished setting up `TLS` with `let's encrypt.`
my site under WordPress is only displayed in ugly HTML.

my architecture is the following:

```
(reverse proxy) => (nat box)=>(reverse proxy2)=>(web server)
```

I obviously changed the `WordPress` configuration for `https`.

Do you have any idea where this might be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-letsencrypt-ssl/#description. The plugin could force SSL/HTTPS, fixing insecure content & mixed content issues easily.

Answer (score 0):

Access your site via browser and check the console. You will probably see resources (probably your css) that are being prevented to load because they are 'http' requests in a 'https' connection.

Comment: that's exactly what's going on.
and it only affects the home page. /
the other pages are displayed normally.
After changing the links in http by https, the first page remains unchanged.
I can't find where is the code of the index.php page to modify it.


thanks you put me on the right track